# activate link after slide to unlock... jquery

Tags: jquery, hyperlink, slider

I have a jquery plugin that i'm working with for a website and I had a quick question... It's a "slide to unlock" plugin that looks just like the iPhone... I was wondering how I would allow people to slide the unlock button and then be forwarded to a link upon completion of slide... Here's the sourcecode I'm working with:

```
$(function() {

$("#slider").draggable({
    axis: 'x',
    containment: 'parent',
    drag: function(event, ui) {
        if (ui.position.left > 550) {
            $("#well").fadeOut();
        } else {
            // Apparently Safari isn't allowing partial opacity on text with background clip? Not sure.
            // $("h2 span").css("opacity", 100 - (ui.position.left / 5))
        }
    },
    stop: function(event, ui) {
        if (ui.position.left < 551) {
            $(this).animate({
                left: 0
            })
        }
    }
});

$('#slider')[0].addEventListener('touchmove', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var el = event.target;
    var touch = event.touches[0];
    curX = touch.pageX - this.offsetLeft - 73;
    if(curX <= 0) return;
    if(curX > 550){
        $('#well').fadeOut();
    }
    el.style.webkitTransform = 'translateX(' + curX + 'px)'; 
}, false);

$('#slider')[0].addEventListener('touchend', function(event) {  
    this.style.webkitTransition = '-webkit-transform 0.3s ease-in';
    this.addEventListener( 'webkitTransitionEnd', function( event ) { this.style.webkitTransition = 'none'; }, false );
    this.style.webkitTransform = 'translateX(0px)';
}, false);

});
```

thanks in advance for the help, I'm not quite a javascript expert but I think it needs be after `$("#well").fadeOut();` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You said you have a link - assuming you do:

```
$("#well").fadeOut('fast',function(){
    window.location = $('#myLink').attr('href');
});
```

If you just want to redirect to a url:

```
$("#well").fadeOut('fast',function(){
    window.location = 'http://www.foobar.com';
});
```

Comment: In that example you would have a hyperlink that looked like <a id="myLink" href="http://foo.bar.com"></a>. JQuery finds objects using css selectors. In the case of #, it's the id of a dom element. So $("#foo") would find a dom element with an id of foo.